# How can I change readline settings on keypress?

Tags: bash, readline

I checked docs for readline (in man bash), and I can't find a way to solve one problem: how to change readline setting (set ... on/off) on keypress?

Keybindings seem to have form:

```
key:function
```

or

```
key:"string to enter"
```

but when I tried:

```
key:set .... off
```

it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bind` builtin command with `-x` option.

A variable may be set with `bind "set var val"`
`bind -x keyseq:command` cause command to be executed when keyseq is entered
So, `bind -x 'keyseq:bind "set var val"'` works fine.

**Example**:

```
bind 'set expand-tilde off'
bind -v | grep expand-tilde
# outputs set expand-tilde off
bind -x '"\C-x\C-t": bind "set expand-tilde on"'
```

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

```
bind -v | grep expand-tilde
# outputs set expand-tilde on
```

Details in `help bind`